# How do royalty fees work on the OpenSea and Rarible?

Tags: blockchain, erc-721, nft, opensea

Suppose the creator mints the NFT on the OpenSea platform, but the NFT is later sold on Rarible or some other platform. Creator won't get the royalty fee in this case as per OpenSea documentation.

Later, the same NFT is sold on the OpenSea platform. Will the creator get the royalty fee this time?

Answer (score 1):

The Royalty fees are probably handled by the openSea Contract.  And yes that is what they promote, that you will get royalty on subsequent sell.

I doubt that the royalties would get applied on another exchange but if it's back to Opensea again and get sold I presume you would get the royalty since your back on Opensea.